# What is the proper way to write a Minitest test for a method that yields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest

I have a method in a class defined as follows:

```
  def show_benefits_section?
    yield if has_any_context?
  end
```

I would like to write a test around this, so far I have this (which works):

```
  test_class.stub(:has_any_context?, true) do
    test_class.show_benefits_section? do |show_section=true|
      assert_equal(show_section, true)
    end
  end
```

I'm just not sure if this is the best way to test that method...
And how do I test for the negative condition?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your code is testing nothing and it always succeeds no matter what.  Try this, which succeeds, to demonstrate the point:

```
[1].each do |first=nil, second=2|
  assert_equal(1, first)
  assert_equal(2, second)
end
```

Let me exaplain; the variable `second` is always 2, no matter what, as the method `each` does not affect it and the default is set to be 2.  By contrast, the default value `nil` for `first` is ignored, beucase `each` passes an object.

Here is an improved code snippet to test your case.
It tests both the cases where the block returns true and false, and both the cases where `has_any_context?` is true and false.  I do not think there is a general way to validate specifically the yielded value from the block. Instead you validate what the methods returns.

```
# Test: :has_any_context? == true 
test_class.stub(:has_any_context?, true) do
  # Test: a block must be given.
  assert_raises(LocalJumpError) { test_class.show_benefits_section? }

  # Test: yield
  [true, false, 5].each do |tobe|
    # If 5 is given, 5 is returned.
    ret = test_class.show_benefits_section? do
      tobe
    end
    assert_equal(tobe, ret)
  end
end

# Test: :has_any_context? == false
test_class.stub(:has_any_context?, false) do
  ret = test_class.show_benefits_section?{true}
  assert_nil(ret)
end
```

Note that your method `show_benefits_section?` returns whatever returned from the block.  My example above tests it, too, by giving a random value, 5. In Ruby's convention, a method name ending with '?' should return either true or false (though there are exceptions like `FileTest.size?`).  If you want to follow the convention, the easiest way is perhaps to rewrite the relevant part as

```
!!yield if has_any_context?
```

You can confirm the test above fails now, once you have done this modification.

Comment: Thanks @Masa!  Couple of questions, why does your test array have `true, false, and 5`?  Is there any significance?  Also, what does the variable `tobe` represent?

Comment: The variable `tobe` represents the value the block returns, which is yielded in the method `show_benefits_section?`. Your method `show_benefits_section?` (as in your post) returns whatever value returned from the block as it is. My code in the answer tests when true/false/5 is returned from the given block, the method `show_benefits_section?` certainly returns true/false/5, respectively.  That is what the last paragraph of my answer explains.

Comment: Correction. Your method `show_benefits_section?` returns whatever value returned from the block as it is, **if** the block is read.  If the block is not read, that is, `if has_any_context?` fails, nil is returned. The last part of the test in my answer tests the case when nil is returned.